# Insert both two tables with FK relationship in one UoW?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following two table with FK relationship.

```
create table A { Id int primary key identity(1,1), ... }
create table B { AId int reference A(Id), ....}
```

Now I need to add a row in A and then add another row in B which will reference the `Id` of new row in A. Is it possible to do it in one unit of work using EF 6? However, the `Id` of A will not be available until the `SaveChanges()` is called? The two inserts have to be separated?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

You need multiple SaveChanges only if you are adding related entities by foreign key primitive values.

If you just want to use a single SaveChanges, add the root entity with the related entity populated as well. (not just the foreign key, the whole related entity object)

```
var tableAEntity = new TableAEntity
{
 // set tableA fields
 // Name = "blah",

 // now set the TableB navigation property reference
 TableBEntityField = new TableBEntity
                     {
                      // table B fields
                     }
};

context.TableAEntities.Add(tableAEntity);
context.SaveChanges();
```

also, i don't want to distract you from the problem at hand.. (and people have always followed that statement with some distracting theory.. so here goes :))

an unit of work pattern doesn't mean, you shouldn't have multiple SaveChanges or anything.
i have found it less intuitive and redundant to actually abstract the Context into an UOW wrapper, especially with EF 6 Code first.

instead, i prefer my business layer manager/operation class to have the Context injected and the methods, just do multiple SaveChanges on it as needed. (without a UOW wrapper in between)

ultimately, the important thing is for your CustomerManager or CustomerOperation concrete class in your business layer, to receive a Customer Domain model, and add it to the database internally. The caller works off an interface ICustomerManager/ICustomerOperation/ICustomerRepository etc, and doesn't know how the concrete classes do persistence.. could be EF DataContext, LINQ2SQL, ADO.NET etc. In that case, the concrete class method can decide to do multiple SaveChanges or span transactions etc. And i have found this option to be more predictable by Saving one entity, then saving another entity with the FK Id etc.

as i said, there maybe varying opinions on UOW :), so choose the solution suitable for your space.

Comment: What if table B has foreign key references on two or more tables which all have identity columns?

Comment: if the 2 more table records are also to be created as part of this method, then just repeat the pattern.. tablebentity = new tablebentity { tablec = new tablec, tabled = new tabled} etc... if the 2 more table records are already in the DB, then you need to read them separately and set the FK on the tablebentity record.. and as i said, if it gets too complex or error-prone (nested entities have been tricky for me), it is absolutely okay to do multiple save changes..